# How can i fetch value of currently deleted Row in Sql trigger and update another table with the deleted row data

Tags: mysql, sql

i am firing a SQL Trigger whenever user deletes the data from table .i want to update another table before deleting the current data .i am unable to get  the current deleted Row Data. How can i get the content of current deleted data in SQL Trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert_money` BEFORE DELETE ON `payment`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE TEMP INT;
    SELECT   OLD.user_id  into TEMP      
    FROM OLD;

    UPDATE user set monthly_limit=TEMP where id=1;

 END
```

Comment: but i reckon it would be better if you save all data deleted in another table.

Answer (score 2):

this will work as you wanted the content deleted :

```
SELECT * FROM NS_WORDS;

mani
nikhil
sugandh
mining
_lkdnsad
_lkdndsadnjas
_lk
_ja
_ls
_lsa

create table deleted_vals(a varchar(20));

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_deleted_vals
BEFORE DELETE
   ON NS_WORDS
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO deleted_vals VALUES(:old.a);
END;
/

delete from NS_WORDS where rownum=1;

SELECT * FROM deleted_vals;

mani

for your table it would be like:

    CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_money
    BEFORE DELETE ON payment
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN

    UPDATE user set monthly_limit=:old.user_id where id=1;

 END;
 /
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to refer to `OLD.userid` instead of storing into another variable `TEMP`. Also, there is no `OLD` table that you can use in the `FROM` clause. You just need to use `OLD.<column name>` to use particular column's value for the row being deleted.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert_money` BEFORE DELETE ON `payment`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE user set monthly_limit = OLD.user_id where id=1;

  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```